# VB macro to group by one column and sum based on row values on another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel with 3 columns:

```
date,       code, sales
-----------------------
1-1-2016,   A,    10

1-1-2016,   B,    20

1-1-2016,   C,    30

1-1-2016,   D,    40

1-2-2016,   A,    50

1-2-2016,   B,    60

1-2-2016,   C,    70

1-2-2016,   D,    80
-----------------------
```

So the code A, B, C, D repeats for multiple dates. Above is just a sample.

For each date, I need to add the sales for A and C as one row. And the sales for B and D as another row.

So my output should look like:

```
1-1-2016,AC,40

1-1-2016,BD,60

1-2-2016,AC,120

1-2-2016,BD,140
```

How can I create a VB macro to accomplish this?

Comment: how have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like below and tweak it as per your need.

```
Sub SummarizeData()
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim x, y, dict, it
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sws = Sheets("Sheet1")
On Error Resume Next
Set dws = Sheets("Summary")
dws.Cells.Clear

If dws Is Nothing Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=sws).Name = "Summary"
    Set dws = ActiveSheet
End If

sws.Range("A1:C1").Copy dws.Range("A1")
x = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    If x(i, 2) = "A" Or x(i, 2) = "C" Then
        If Not dict.exists(x(i, 1) & ";AC") Then
            dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";AC") = x(i, 3)
        Else
            dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";AC") = dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";AC") + x(i, 3)
        End If
    ElseIf x(i, 2) = "B" Or x(i, 2) = "D" Then
        If Not dict.exists(x(i, 1) & ";BD") Then
            dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";BD") = x(i, 3)
        Else
            dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";BD") = dict.Item(x(i, 1) & ";BD") + x(i, 3)
        End If
    End If
Next i
ReDim y(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 3)

i = 1

For Each it In dict.keys
    y(i, 1) = Split(it, ";")(0)
    y(i, 2) = Split(it, ";")(1)
    y(i, 3) = dict.Item(it)
    i = i + 1
Next it

dws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(y, 1), 3).Value = y
dws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```